# GUI tool to set the screen brightness

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, brightness

What GUI tool can I use to set the screen brightness?

Answer (score 1):

The best tool I could find is [RedshiftGUI](https://github.com/maoserr/redshiftgui/).

[image]

**Installation**

1. [Download](https://github.com/maoserr/redshiftgui/downloads) RedshiftGUI DEB package
2. Choose  32 or 64  package
3. In terminal `sudo dpkg -i RedshiftGUI*.deb`

Comment: There is no brightness in latest relese

Answer (score 1):

I know of two alternatives. One is through **System Settings -> Brightness & Lock**.

Second, install this [brightness indicator](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/brightness-control-ubuntu), which I totally love, by the way

Answer (score 1):

You can install "Brightness Controller" via ppa repository:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install brightness-controller
```

Source: https://www.ostechnix.com/brightness-controller-simple-gui-application-control-brightness-ubuntu/

Comment: @Someone, I see that my answer now included above by you.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote something simple. Here: https://github.com/ceremcem/brightness-control-gui//

[image]

Answer (score 1):

<sub>the article from where this answer is taken from was made for older releases but it is still working on 20.04 (tested)</sub>

***All credits go to [ostechnix.com](https://ostechnix.com/brightness-controller-simple-gui-application-control-brightness-ubuntu/) and [@VasinYuriy 's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1235362/1460940)***

> #### Brightness Controller - A Simple GUI Application To Control The Brightness In Ubuntu And Derivatives
>
> **Install Brightness Controller** The developer has made a PPA for Ubuntu and its derivatives. So, installation won;t be a big deal. To
> install it, run the following commands one by one: `$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller $ sudo apt-get update $ sudo apt-get install brightness-controller`
> **Please be mindful that it is compatible with python2 only.**
>
> The usage is absolutely easy. Once installed, launch "Brightness
> Controller" from Menu. This is how the default interface looks like.
>
> **Control the brightness in Ubuntu using Brightness Controller**
>
> [image]
>
> Just move the vertical sliders up or down to adjust the brightness.
>
> If you have four displays, then you can install simpler version of
> Brightness Controller to have four four display brightness sliders,
> one for each. `$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller $ sudo apt-get update $ sudo apt-get install brightness-controller-simple` Here is how simpler
> version of Brightness Controller looks like.
>
> [image]